# Software for live streaming - sequencing videos and overlays

Tags: video, video-editing, streaming

I'm learning about video streaming, and I was curious if there was software to sequence recorded content to stream live, like how music video channels would spontaneously add different videos to the mix (and how it would play automatically once listed).

Also if it can do overlays - I noticed that when I was watching Yogscast doing streams that they had dynamic* overlays built into the stream and not the video player.

Heck, anything to do with how to manage long streams of videos would be pertinent. I'm curious about how it'd be to do a live streamed video channel for shows that seem interesting to me.

*could be dynamically edited in, and also showed up whenever people donated

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to create your own software to do this on hardware you already have, I would recommend checking out the [LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/engine/multimedia) for this type of application. This library contains programmatic interfaces for C, C++, COM, and .NET applications. The LEADTOOLS Media Server would allow you to support basically any device with your video stream. You could provide either file or live sources to it.

This SDK has serveral different overlay filters you might find useful including stamps, text or video overlays. There is also a callback filter in case you want to do your own custom editing of every frame to be streamed.

Disclaimer: I am an employee of the company that wrote this library.

Answer (score 0):

Of course many studios use **very** expensive hardware and proprietary, or even custom, software to go with the hardware to do the sort of thing that you are looking at, we are talking tens or hundreds of thousands of pounds/dollars.

For a good starting point for home/amateur/study use can I suggest that you take a look at [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/)

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross platform - will work on Windows/OS-X/Linux - *people are even using it on RaspberryPi*,
- Create a stream from a file or from an input stream, see [here](https://sonnati.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/ffmpeg-%E2%80%93-the-swiss-army-knife-of-internet-streaming-%E2%80%93-part-iv/),
- Transcode on the fly, (if your machine is powerful enough),
- You can add overlays of Text, Images &/or videos, etc.

I would also suggest taking a look at [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) to pick up some tips.

For a simpler to use video streaming solution, *without having to write any code,* please take a look at the [streaming](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo) capabilities of [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and at the [Video LAN Manager](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/VLM/).

Comment: Thanks. That is a really good idea actually. While I was reading through some of the info on FFMPEG I was thinking about making an offline playlist, and maybe doing non-live edits on videos and then just processing them into playlist format. Then showing that live, which might work. I'm interested in seeing it from programming angles, as I'm sure that there are plenty of ways to go about it. Especially if I want to avoid all the streaming being done from one computer.

Comment: One more vote for both ffmpeg and vlc for on the cheap experimentatio.  Have used VLC to send to a wowza media server, which then broadcast to the world, worked good. As said, for real fancy stuff you're looking at custom/packaged stuff - I'd recommend looking at what TriCaster offers...   No matter which way, there are hosting companies (like wowza) that will accept your feed and broadcast to the world for very low fees ($5/day for wowza I think...)

Answer (score 0):

Screen recorder studio is a great choice for streaming and overlaying. You can find screenshots and more information about it using the link below.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/screen-recorder-studio-screen-recorder-based-on-obs-studio/9p94835tm2lv?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Screen recorder studio is basically based on OBS Studio. Link for OBS studio - https://obsproject.com/